# Deep collection in a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a JSON object below:

```
{
    "JOHN": {
        "class": "ABC",
        "meta": {
            "Math": [
                {
                    "id": "math_point",
                    "name": "Math Point",
                    "type": "comparable"
                },
                {
                    "id": "math_switch",
                    "name": "Math Switch",
                    "type": "switch"
                }
            ],
            "History": [
                {
                    "id": "history_point",
                    "name": "Math Point",
                    "type": "comparable"
                },
                {
                    "id": "history_switch",
                    "name": "Math Switch",
                    "type": "switch"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "BOB": {
      "class": "DFE",
      "meta": {
          "Math": [
              {
                  "id": "math_point",
                  "name": "Math Point",
                  "type": "comparable"
              },
              {
                  "id": "math_switch",
                  "name": "Math Switch",
                  "type": "switch"
              }
          ],
          "Biology": [
              {
                  "id": "biology_point",
                  "name": "Biology Point",
                  "type": "comparable"
              },
              {
                  "id": "biology_switch",
                  "name": "Biology Switch",
                  "type": "switch"
              }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Which best way to use Lodash or VanilaJS to return( unique `id` ):

```
[
  {
      "id": "math_point",
      "name": "Math Point",
      "type": "comparable"
  },
  {
      "id": "math_switch",
      "name": "Math Switch",
      "type": "switch"
  },
  {
      "id": "history_point",
      "name": "Math Point",
      "type": "comparable"
  },
  {
      "id": "history_switch",
      "name": "Math Switch",
      "type": "switch"
  },
  {
    "id": "biology_point",
    "name": "Biology Point",
    "type": "comparable"
  },
  {
    "id": "biology_switch",
    "name": "Biology Switch",
    "type": "switch"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extact the arrays with  `Object.values`. Flatten those into a single array, and then use a Map, keyed by `id`, to reduce this to a unique set of values:

```js
let obj = {"JOHN": {"class": "ABC","meta": {"Math": [{"id": "math_point","name": "Math Point","type": "comparable"},{"id": "math_switch","name": "Math Switch","type": "switch"}],"History": [{"id": "history_point","name": "Math Point","type": "comparable"},{"id": "history_switch","name": "Math Switch","type": "switch"}]}},"BOB": {"class": "DFE","meta": {"Math": [{"id": "math_point","name": "Math Point","type": "comparable"},{"id": "math_switch","name": "Math Switch","type": "switch"}],"Biology": [{"id": "biology_point","name": "Biology Point","type": "comparable"},{"id": "biology_switch","name": "Biology Switch","type": "switch"}]}}};

let arr = Array.from(new Map(
    Object.values(obj)
          .flatMap(({meta}) => Object.values(meta))
          .flat()
          .map(o => [o.id, o])
).values());

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to parse JSON in to javascript object and then you could use a temporary object to hold all the unique keys and their corresponsing objects. After that, you could extract the objects from the temporary object using `Object.values()` function

```js
const obj = {"JOHN": {"class": "ABC","meta": {"Math": [{"id": "math_point","name": "Math Point","type": "comparable"},{"id": "math_switch","name": "Math Switch","type": "switch"}],"History": [{"id": "history_point","name": "Math Point","type": "comparable"},{"id": "history_switch","name": "Math Switch","type": "switch"}]}},"BOB": {"class": "DFE","meta": {"Math": [{"id": "math_point","name": "Math Point","type": "comparable"},{"id": "math_switch","name": "Math Switch","type": "switch"}],"Biology": [{"id": "biology_point","name": "Biology Point","type": "comparable"},{"id": "biology_switch","name": "Biology Switch","type": "switch"}]}}};

const temp = {};
Object.values(obj).forEach(({meta}) => {
  Object.values(meta).flat().forEach(o => (temp[o.id] = o));
});

const result = Object.values(temp);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As This question is tagged as lodash how about just simply use this:

`_.flatMapDeep(input, e => Object.values(e.meta))`

It is more readable.

Since you are interested about only the values ob each meta object. All the values of each meta objects are a array (values, not the keys) and you are basically looking into the contents of those arrays, thats it. so just simply take all of them and make flatten in lodash.

Let's have a snippet:

```js
let input = {"JOHN":{"class":"ABC","meta":{"Math":[{"id":"math_point","name":"Math Point","type":"comparable"},{"id":"math_switch","name":"Math Switch","type":"switch"}],"History":[{"id":"history_point","name":"Math Point","type":"comparable"},{"id":"history_switch","name":"Math Switch","type":"switch"}]}},"BOB":{"class":"DFE","meta":{"Math":[{"id":"math_point","name":"Math Point","type":"comparable"},{"id":"math_switch","name":"Math Switch","type":"switch"}],"Biology":[{"id":"biology_point","name":"Biology Point","type":"comparable"},{"id":"biology_switch","name":"Biology Switch","type":"switch"}]}}},
    res = _.flatMapDeep(input, e => Object.values(e.meta));
    
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = Object.values(obj)
let ids = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < Object.values(arr[i].meta).length; j++){
    for(let k = 0; k < Object.values(arr[i].meta)[j].length; k++){
      ids.push(Object.values(arr[i].meta)[j][k].id)
    }
  }
}

console.log([...new Set(ids)])
```

This returns all the unique IDs